# F# JSON Type Provider error: This token is reserved for future use

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm trying to compile simple example:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data

type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
let simple = Simple.Parse(""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """)
simple.Age
simple.Name
```

I use MSVS 2010, .Net Framework 4.5.1 and FSharp.Data via nuget. But when I try to compile this example, I get error:

This token (`<"""`, `""">`, `(""")` and `""")`) is reserved for future use.

How can I use F# Json Type Provider?

Comment: Probably add a space between `<` and `"""`.  I suspect you are confusing the parser

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm trying to compile example from docs  http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type providers are part of F# 3.0. Are you sure, you are using the F# 3.0 or F# 3.1 compiler? I thought Visual Studio 2010 came with F# 2.0.

I remember, that the `"""` strings were also added in F# 3.0